# Autosys - triggering a job on machine reboot

Tags: boot, scheduled-task

We're using Autosys (Computer Associates) to periodically restart some of our app servers. Can we configure Autosys to run the job when the machine reboots, regardless of time?

Currently if our server falls over we have to restart the jobs manually following reboot, and we'd like to manage this through Autosys to keep all the configuration in one place.

It seems like there should be something simple we can add to the .jil but I can't find a reference on the web. Or, is there some pseudo-job which Autosys runs on host reboot to which we could attach our own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Autosys, but you could just put the job in /etc/rc.local to have it start after boot, or you could use a local process monitor like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to start the job.